# How we can open the filtered port again?

Tags: ssh, nmap, ports

I had a root access from a Server over SSH on 2200 port but, recently I can not connect to it ,so after checking via nmap turns out the port is filtered by admin or someone .

```
Host is up (0.011s latency).
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
2200/tcp filtered ici
```

I have a php shell on that server; after checking the `passwd` figures my root user is still there,so the question is how can I connect to the server again ?
p.s : the bind port and the back connect won't work on it after filtering !

Comment: I'm not sure how we can help with the available data

Answer (score 2):

"*filtered by admin or someone*" is quite blurry

- Don't you have **any** idea of what service could be filtering the port ?

  Did you install some software, run some scripts, or made some configuration changes, which could have caused that ?
- If you're afraid of losing access to your server, **consider installing Webmin**. It will grant you root access from a browser without needing to restart or change the config of your SSH server.
- If you can't find why the port is filtered, you still can change your SSH config to use another port, but of course, not solving the cause remains, in itsef, a quite serious issue.

Comment: Thnx 1++ , but in third paragraph you told I can change SSH config by apache access ? as I told right now I can't connect to my server via ssh

Comment: @Sam SSH and apache are two different things.  On the debian servers I'm used to admin, my SSH config is in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. The port is the first option (a simple lines with just `Port 22`).  This may vary depending on your distro and ssh server.
Also, will you still have access to your server if you lose your current connection (e.g. physical access) ? Playing with SSH service config might disconnect you, so **be sure you'll still be able to connect to your server !**.
Anyway, the first thing you should look for is : **_What_** is filtering the port

Comment: I know that man ! :) apache is the access of mine from the server ! with this access I can't connect to ssh and change it

Comment: I missed the `php` part about your shell. I thought you had an opened _ssh_ session still running, and were unable to open new ones.
If you can't su to root in any way, and if your shell is limited to what the www-data user can do, I'm afraid you're in trouble.
If you're lucky enough, Webmin might already be on your server, granting you a root access (some images or distros include it by default). Else, and without physical access, I'd start out by restarting the server.
btw, more infos would help a lot.  What does filter the port, why can't you disable/remove it ? Who manages this server ?